# How to configure multiple nested subdirectories in Nginx using wildcards?

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, web-applications

Sorry if this was asked before. I've searched, but couldn't find anything close to what I'm trying to accomplish and I would appreciate any indication that could get me closer to solving this.

**I have the following server setup:**

- **domain.com** - Serves a WordPress site proxy passed to `php-fpm`.
- **domain.com/{directory}/{subdirectory}** - Serves static HTML files for all the **{subdirectories}** I've placed inside **{directory}**. See location block below *(placed above the / location with the PHP proxy pass)*:

  ```
  location ^~ /my_dir {
      alias /var/www/domain.com/my_dir;
      index index.html index.htm;
  }
  ```

Pretty basic so far.

**Problem:**

However, one of the directory inside **{my_dir}** is a Vue app that's using front-end routing. All works fine until the browser is refreshed and Nginx returns 404 due to the fact that there's no **domain.com/{my_dir}/{vue_app_dir}/{vue_path}** available. In order to fix this, I would have to redirect any server request from **{vue_path}** to **{vue_app_dir}/index.html**.

I've tried multiple combinations of server blocks above the one I posted earlier but with no success.

Again, I'm sorry if this was answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `my_dir` in the `location` directive and the `alias` directive are the same name, you can use `root` instead. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

You can add another `location` for the Vue app, and include a `try_files` statement to avoid the 404 responses. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /my_dir {
    root /var/www/domain.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
location ^~ /my_dir/vue_app {
    root /var/www/domain.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /my_dir/vue_app/index.html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Richard! I tried a similar location block, but haven't thought of using `try_files $uri $uri/ /my_dir/vue_app/index.html;`. You just saved me a lot of time. I really appreciate it! 